# SliverList not updating on setState to a new List

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a SliverList with children that I populate in initState(). I have a filter option that allows me to filter by different attributes of the children. In initState I create the 4 different lists; an unfiltered list, 2 filtered list and then a listToShow, with listToShow and unfiltered list having the same elements. ListToShow is the list that I draw on the screen, when a filter button is pressed, I assign the correct filtered list to the listToShow within a setState(). However, the list doesn't update on screen. If I print out the values, I can see that it changes.

If I try listToShow = [] this results in an empty list on screen! I'm not sure what is going wrong.

```
bool filterByRisk = false;
bool filterByIssue = false;
Filter filter = new Filter();
List<ProjectCard> unfilteredList = new List();
List<ProjectCard> riskFilteredList = new List();
List<ProjectCard> issueFilteredList = new List();
List<ProjectCard> listToShow = new List();

@override
void initState() {
  for (Project project in portfolio.projects) {
    unfilteredList.add(ProjectCard(
      project: project,
    ));
    riskFilteredList.add(ProjectCard(
      project: project,
    ));
    issueFilteredList.add(ProjectCard(
      project: project,
    ));
    listToShow.add(ProjectCard(
      project: project,
    ));
  }
  riskFilteredList = filter.filterProject(riskFilteredList, 'risk');
  issueFilteredList = filter.filterProject(issueFilteredList, 'issue');
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    backgroundColor: Color(0xFF1e9eb9),
    body: Stack(
      children: [
        CustomScrollView(
          controller: _scrollController,
          slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverAppBar(
              expandedHeight: 150,
              backgroundColor: Color(0xFF59c2cf),
              pinned: true,
              floating: false,
              title: Text(portfolio.name + "'s Portfolio"),
              flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                collapseMode: CollapseMode.parallax,
                background: ClipPath(
                  clipper: MyClipper(),
                  child: Container(
                    color: Color(0xFF1e9eb9),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SliverList(
              delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                createList(),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        _buildFab()
      ],
    ),
  );
}

List<ProjectCard> createList() {
  setState(() {
    if (filterByIssue) {
      listToShow = issueFilteredList;
    } else if (filterByRisk) {
      print("RISK");
      listToShow = riskFilteredList;
      for (ProjectCard p in listToShow) {
        print(p.project.name);
      }
    } else {
      listToShow = unfilteredList;
    }
  });
  return listToShow;
}

void issuePressed() {
  setState(() {
    filterByIssue = !filterByIssue;
  });
}

void riskPressed() {
  setState(() {
    filterByRisk = !filterByRisk;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing the setState from your createList() method, it's typically not recommended to do setSet during the build.

You don't need to keep track all those lists, there is better ways but other than that the logic should be fine and still work. I don't see anything else off.

Comment: Just tried that there and unfortunately that didn't work. Yeah I know it's definitely not the best way to do it, I'm trying to simplify the problem for the time being until I can get the list to change :) . The list is using my own stateful widgets, would this have something to do with it?

Comment: I'm not sure that I see anything wrong. It's hard to say without seeing the rest of the code. Using your own stateful widgets is okay, really when you call setState all it means is re-call the build method on this widget and all widgets under this widget tree.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `SliverFillRemaining`.

Set the `listToShow` variable in `setState` body.